# Test Impact Analysis tool for Python

Tags: python, unit-tests

Is there a Test Impact Analysis (TIA) framework/tool/extension for Python? E.g. an equivalent to JAVAs [Test Impact Analysis Plugin for jQAssistant](https://github.com/jqassistant-contrib/jqassistant-test-impact-analysis-plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few libraries out there you could try. Here are some entrypoints:

- [`python-tia`](https://python-tia.readthedocs.io/) - this is my preference
- ["Potential Alternatives" page in `pytest-tia`'s docs](https://python-tia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/alternatives.html). You can use this as a starting point to comparing alternatives.

Note that TIA is rarely perfect (especially imperfect in dynamic languages), so use with caution.

One pattern to consider is to use a mixed approach. I like to use TIA to exclude some slow tests on branches *until they have a merge-request*. So master, tags, and merge-requests run full suite. [I'm using GitLabCI for this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/#excluding-certain-jobs) (`only: ['merge_requests']`) but you can do it with some other tools too.

Lastly here are some reading materials.

- 2015, ["Reducing Test Times by Only Running Impacted Tests - Python Edition" by Paul Hammant](https://paulhammant.com/2015/01/18/reducing-test-times-by-only-running-impacted-tests-python-edition/) ([archive.org snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011130150/https://paulhammant.com/2015/01/18/reducing-test-times-by-only-running-impacted-tests-python-edition/))
- 2017, ["The Rise of Test Impact Analysis" by Paul Hammant](https://martinfowler.com/articles/rise-test-impact-analysis.html) ([archive.org snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308172628/https://martinfowler.com/articles/rise-test-impact-analysis.html))

Comment: `python-tia` is my own package :) I created it after accepting that there were no suitable alternatives available back when asking...

Comment: @thinwybk Hah! And now I see, it's the same avatar. Did not notice it before. Well, kudos!